# Node.js redirect error : Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, header, response

I am getting one redirect error message after submit form in node.js, so after inserting data to mongodb i am getting one error message "Can't set headers after they are sent".

```
var friendslist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

    for(var i=0; i<friendslist.length; i++){
        var userid = friendslist[i];
        var name = friendslist[i];
        var number = friendslist[i];
        var status = friendslist[i];
        var currentUserid = friendslist[i];

        var friends = [{"userid" : userid.name, 
                        "name" : name.name,
                        "number" : number.number,
                        "status" : status.status,
                        "currentUserid" : currentUserid.currentUserid}];

        collection.insert(friends, function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({error : "database error"});
            }
            else {
                collection.find().toArray(function(err, users) {
                    res.json(users);
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
```

So after insert all data to mongodb i am sending one json response to the user but after that i am getting that error message.

Please kindly go through my post and suggest me some solution.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not all of it, somewhere before `res.json` you have something that is outputting content, like `res.send`, `res.render` etc. What's probably happening is that you're sending something, and later on you're trying to send `json`, which is trying to set certain headers, but it can't set headers after content is already sent.

Comment: You are running the `collection.insert` code inside for loop. Once completing the first insert the response is sent to client, for second iteration there will be no `downlink` connection as its been completed in the first iteration. You have to insert all the collection then call `res.json` wrapping with `promise` and calling `promise.all` after the complete operation.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't make database calls in loops if you're expecting a response.
Also, when using express, call `res.send` or `res.json` only when you're ready to send back data to your user.

```
var friendslist = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)); 
var friends = [];
for(var i=0; i<friendslist.length; i++){
    var friend = friendslist[i]

    friends.push({
        "userid" : friend.userid, 
        "name" : friend.name,
        "number" : friend.number,
        "status" : friend.status,
        "currentUserid" : friend.currentUserid
    }); 
}

collection.insert(friends, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({error : "database error"});
    }
    else {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, users) {
            res.json(users);
        });
    } 
});
```